# Visual Studio 2017で、デバッグすると現れる表示画面の大きさ

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2017で、iPhone6 のサイズでUWPのアプリを作成中です。　
数ページのデザイン画面内の下の方に、ボタン (Topに戻る) を置いています。デバッグ後ボタンを押してTopに戻ることはできるのですが、ボタンは全部表示されてなく上部だけの表示です。

デバッグすると現れる画面が、ずっと下部分(全体の5％位)が表示されないのですが、これはデザインを全体に上にあげないといけないのでしょうか？
デバッグ後にあらわれる画面の拡大・縮小ができるのであれば、その方法をお願いします。(初心者です)

Comment: どのようなプロジェクトで何のサイズを問題としているのかよく分かりません。画面キャプチャやソースコードを追加してください。

Comment: iPhone6 のサイズでUWPのアプリを作成中です。

Comment: @nt8ais さん、スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ。このサイトでは質問文の下の「編集」から自由に追記できるようになっています。コメントは後から見に来た方からは読みにくいので、是非質問文を直接編集してください。また、今回のご質問は見え方に関するものですので、ソースコードだけではなくスクリーンショットなどもあると、何を問題としているのかが第三者に伝わりやすいと思います。